# Number included in next iteration if smaller numbers in this iteration occur odd number of times

Tags: sequences-and-series, algorithms, arithmetic

Let's start with a sequence
$1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, \ldots upto n$.

Now we will at each iteration apply the following to the sequence --

If for any integer $x$, the number of times integers $\le x$ appear in the current sequence is odd, we include the integer $x$ in the next iteration of the sequence.

As an example:

Iteration $1$: $1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, \ldots $

Iteration $2$: $1, 3, 5, 7, 9, \ldots $

Iteration $3$: $1, 2, 5, 6, 9, 10, \ldots $

Iteration $4$: $1, 5, 9, \ldots $

Iteration $5$: $1, 2, 3, 4, 9, 10, \ldots $

I would like to know if there is any way to find out the sequence at $i$th iteration without starting from iteration $1$. Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: It seems to me that your construction was intended for *increasing* sequences, so that determining how many times an entry less than or equal to $x$ appears can be done.  If a sequence were allowed to decrease, then the number of such entries might be infinite or impossible to know with certainty.

Comment: It is possible to see that $1$ will always begin the sequence provided $1$ appears in the initial sequence an odd number of times, and this can be generalized (with some difficulty) to deciding whether $x$ will appear in the $i$th iteration.  However you've been remiss in describing with precision what sequences this iteration will be applied to.  In addition to whether the sequence is (weakly) increasing, you should tell Readers if entries can repeat in the first iteration.

Comment: the initial sequence would be 1 2 3 4 .... (upto n)

Comment: The series has nice properties like it has a cyclic nature e.g the series repeats itself after reaching closest 2 power number just over n

Answer (score 0):

First, let's represent each iteration by a sequence of zeroes and ones, where the $i^\text{th}$ position is $1$ if $i$ appears in the current iteration, and $0$ if it does not appear. I'm also going to number the iterations starting from 0, because this will make the pattern nicer later on.

Thus, iteration 0 is represented by `111111111...`

Iteration 1 is represented by `101010101...`

Iteration 2 is represented by `110011001...`

Iteration 3 is represented by `100010001...`

Iteration 4 is represented by `111100001...`

And so on.

The number of entries $\le x$ in a sequence corresponds to the sum of the first $x$ positions in its binary-sequence representation. Therefore our rule for the $i^\text{th}$ position of each sequence can be "Take the sum of the first $i$ positions of the previous binary sequence. Write down $1$ if the sum is odd, and $0$ if the sum is even" or even more simply "Write down the sum modulo 2".

If we skip the "modulo 2" part of the definition, the rule is that the $i^\text{th}$ position of each sequence is the sum of the first $i$ positions of the previous sequence, and we get the following sequences:

For iteration 0, we'll start with $1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, \dots$ as before.

For iteration 1, we get $1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, \dots$.

For iteration 2, we get $1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, \dots$.

For iteration 3, we get $1, 4, 10, 20, 35, 56, \dots$.

And so on. You might notice that the sequence in iteration $k$ is the sequence $$\binom kk, \binom{k+1}{k}, \binom{k+2}{k}, \binom{k+3}{k}, \dots.$$ This follows from the "[hockey-stick identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hockey-stick_identity)" $$\binom 0r + \binom 1r + \binom 2r + \dots + \binom nr = \binom{n+1}{r+1},$$ so this pattern continues to hold.

From there, we deduce that the rule for the binary sequences is just that the $i^\text{th}$ entry of iteration $k$ is $\binom{k+i-1}{k} \bmod 2$.

From there, we deduce that the rule for your original sequence is: the positive integer $x$ appears in iteration $k$ if and only if $\binom{k+x-1}{k}$ is odd.

You might also look into [Lucas's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%27s_theorem) for a way to test whether $\binom nk$ is even or odd without computing it directly.